# How to install php extensions via pecl for different php versions on Mac

Tags: php, macos, pecl, apcu

I am not able to install php extensions like apcu for different php versions separately. I am running php7.1 and php7.3 (installed via brew) on MacOS Mojave

I already tried things like 
`pecl -d php_suffix=7.1 install <package>`
as I found this suggestion here. But it doesn't work at all.

The specific problem is to install apcu for php7.1 while php7.3 is also installed. No matter what I do - apcu get's only available for php7.3.

When I run `php -v` I get `PHP 7.1`
When I check the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.30_1/include/php/ext` there is no apcu

Isn't there any way of telling pecl for which version it is supposed to install the extension?

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" isn't very clear. are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Sorry - you're right. 
No - in the specific case when trying to install apcu it just installs the extension for php7.3 - regardless what I do

Answer (score 10):

Now I got it. 
Found it here: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/pecl-with-multiple-php-versions/1977

pecl was linked to `/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.7/bin/pecl`

Pecl comes with each php Version and can be found (for example) in `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.30_1/bin`

Now you just have to cd there and use this explicit version of pecl.

So if one want to install an extension for php7.1:

`/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.30_1/bin/pecl install <package-name>`

So if one want to install an extension for php7.3:

`/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/bin/pecl install <package-name>`